# How to get fastest streaming video using URL in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner in Android ,I am playing  video using URL in my android app but the video is not streaming that much  fast as compare to other app like showbox .l  had also used different url but the result is same  . Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your internet speed and the server response you are using. ShowBox must be using it's own dedicated server, but maybe you are using a third party server that is not so fast.

Another cause in the speed difference can be the size and the quality of video. A video with low quality will take less time to load as compared to a video with high quality.

There is a solution that can work, you have to keep saving packets of data in cache and keep playing the video from cache. In this way App will take some time to start the video but after that it will be working with speed. It's just a small push to your streaming but mainly it depends on the server.

Comment: I am using firebase console server.

Comment: I never worked on Firebase Server for videos.So I am not sure about that.But it you think that server has good response then the only left for you is to save in cache bfore playing